# How to PUT multipart/form-data using Spring MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, spring-test-mvc, mockmvc

I have a controller's method with a `PUT` method, which receives multipart/form-data:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/putIn", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
   public Foo updateFoo(HttpServletRequest request,
                           @RequestBody Foo foo,
                           @RequestParam("foo_icon") MultipartFile file) {
    ...
   }
```

and I want to test it using `MockMvc`. Unfortunately `MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload` creates essentially an instance of `MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder` which has a `POST` method:

```
super(HttpMethod.POST, urlTemplate, urlVariables)
```

**EDIT:**
<strike>Surely I can</strike> **I can not** create my own implementation of `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`, say

```
public MockPutMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder(String urlTemplate, Object... urlVariables) {
    super(HttpMethod.PUT, urlTemplate, urlVariables);
    super.contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
}
```

because `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder` has a package-local constructor.

<strike>But I'm wondering is there any more convenient</strike> Is any way to do this, may be I missed some existent class or method for doing this?

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as the accepted answer? It will help keep StackOverflow clean and efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, and it's simple too!

I ran into the same problem myself. Though I was discouraged by Sam Brannen's answer, it appears that Spring MVC nowadays DOES support PUT file uploading as I could simply do such a request using Postman (I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2). So, I kept digging and found that the only problem is the fact that the `MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder` returned by `MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload()` has the method hardcoded to "POST". Then I discovered the `with()` method...

and that allowed me to come up with this neat little trick to force the `MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder` to use the "PUT" method anyway:

```
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("data", "dummy.csv",
            "text/plain", "Some dataset...".getBytes());

    MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder builder =
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/test1/datasets/set1");
    builder.with(new RequestPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
            request.setMethod("PUT");
            return request;
        }
    });
    mvc.perform(builder
            .file(file))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: This should be solution to the question because it allow to solve the problem of the person who ask the question

Comment: FYI - in spring 5, `fileUpload` is deprecated and should use `multipart` instead. Other than that - works like a charm :)

Comment: with java 8 lambda syntax: `builder.with(request -> { request.setMethod("PUT"); return request; });`

Comment: The `PUT` string can also be retrieved from this constant: `HttpMethod.PUT.name()`

Comment: Spent an half of day and finally encounter this answer thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This is unfortunately currently not supported in Spring MVC Test, and I don't see a work-around other than creating your own custom `MockPutMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder` and copying-n-pasting code from the standard implementation.

For what it's worth, Spring MVC also does not support `PUT` requests for file uploads by default either. The Multipart resolvers are hard coded to accept only `POST` requests for file uploads -- both for Apache Commons and the standard Servlet API support.

If you would like Spring to support `PUT` requests in addition, feel free to [open a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) in Spring's JIRA issue tracker.

Comment: I found a simple solution! Check out my answer

Comment: Spring now also supports any method, not just POST. See [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/bac68c8d3f9ca4caa70b54c14e0e9805f88f8d34#diff-baffaa8d24133e1e64e3e019e2dd877d1fb0f0f2dc43a79fb7567f39dd8f2536)

Answer (score 5):

Translating @HammerNl answer for Kotlin. This worked for me.

```
val file = File("/path/to/file").readBytes()
val multipartFile = MockMultipartFile("image", "image.jpg", "image/jpg", file)

val postProcess = RequestPostProcessor { it.method = "PUT"; it}
mockMvc.perform(
    MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/api/image/$id")
        .file(multipartFile)
        .with(postProcess))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue has been already fixed in V 5.3.22

```
/**
 * Variant of {@link #multipart(String, Object...)} that also accepts an
 * {@link HttpMethod}.
 * @param httpMethod the HTTP method to use
 * @param urlTemplate a URL template; the resulting URL will be encoded
 * @param uriVariables zero or more URI variables
 * @since 5.3.22
 */
public static MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder multipart(HttpMethod httpMethod, String urlTemplate, Object... uriVariables) {
    return new MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder(httpMethod, urlTemplate, uriVariables);
}
```

Comment: So instead of mockMvc.perform(multipart(urlTemplate)... you can now call mockMvc.perform(multipart(HttpMethod.PUT, urlTemplate)...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass both `foo` and `file`

Try rewrite you controller like:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/putIn", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Foo updateFoo(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    @RequestPart Foo foo,
    @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
    ...
}
```

And test looks like:

```java
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "dummy.csv",
            "text/plain", "Some dataset...".getBytes());
    // application/json if you pass json as string
    MockMultipartFile file2 = new MockMultipartFile("foo", "foo.txt",
            "application/json", "Foo data".getBytes());

    MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder builder =
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/test1/datasets/set1");
    builder.with(new RequestPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
            request.setMethod("PUT");
            return request;
        }
    });
    mvc.perform(builder
            .file(file)
            .file(file2))
            .andExpect(status().ok());
```

Comment: Hello. Just tried to do this but I keep getting "Content type 'application/json' not supported" for mockMvc test. I have a controller with two RequestPart, one of them is a POJO and the other a MultipartFile. What I'm doing wrong? Using postman is working fine!