# MockMVC - calling a PUT endpoint that accepts a multipart file

Tags: java, put, multipart, mockmvc

I have a simple PUT endpoint in a Spring Boot application:

```
@PutMapping()
public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@RequestParam("cats") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
```

I'm trying to create a test for the controller using `MockMVC`:

```
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(CatController.class)
public class CatControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

...
```

For `POST` endpoints I use something like that:

```
 MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", new FileInputStream("myCats.csv"));

 mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).alwaysDo(print()).build();

 MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/uploadCats").file(multipartFile))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andReturn();
```

But when trying to translate the above call to PUT endpoint I find that I can create

```
MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/catUpload")
```

But then I can't chain to it the `multipart`

Or I can do:

`MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart(...)`

But then I can't chain to it the `put`.

I saw some post about this problem, but they all were few years old. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using [this great example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40656484/5458827) I was able to solve the issues.

I'm attaching here the code with the minor updates to the post from 2016:

```
        MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder builder =
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/catUpload");
            builder.with(request -> {
                request.setMethod("PUT");
                return request;
            });

     MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(builder
            .file(multipartFile))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 with Spring 5.3.17 it's possible to avoid explicit builder creation leveraging [static multipart request mock builder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#multipart-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) that replaces deprecated [fileUpload](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#fileUpload-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Unfortunately it sill has `method` property hardcoded with `POST` value, forcing you to change it to `PUT` by its `with` method accepting a [RequestPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/RequestPostProcessor.html) as parameter.
Being the latter a Functional Interface, lets you reduce the code by lambda expression to something like this in one of its simplest form, involving just a path parameter with value of 99 and a single file to upload and expecting a `200` response code:

```java
mockMvc.perform(multipart("/endpoint/{pathParameter}/upload_handler", 99)
  .file(mockFileToUpload)
  .with(req -> { req.setMethod("PUT"); return req; }))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
```

At current time I didn't find any RequestPostProcessor implementation giving the ability to apply needed method modification through a builder pattern, so we're still forced using void mutator `setMethod` and explicitly returning mutated argument.